# Can't recognize these handwritten kana (or kanji) in a text

Tags: handwriting

While reading a 1920s handwritten official document, I'm having some trouble to recognize these two kana (or kanji) which the red arrows (see image below) are pointing at. The question here is what kana or kanji are these two symbols?

The content of the text is about a person's health status. And it was wrote under the pre-war Japanese orthography which the native words could be written in katakana.

(I'm a native Chinese speaker and just know a little Japanese vocabulary.)

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 老年ニシテ・・・

(= 老年で・・・/老年なので・・・)

> 視力充分ナラ[ス]{ず}・・・

(= 視力が充分ではなく・・・)